# Xamarin Forms Android: map.Pins.Clear() issue

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

my development team and I have run into an issue on our Android distribution of our Xamarin project. The issue is as such: The application uses an observable collection of objects and represents these objects in the form of a list view and a map view with pins representing the objects. In the map view, our code is designed to subscribe to a messaging center call that periodically updates the observable collection of objects from our API (other part of project). The issue we are having is that when we call PlotPins method in the messaging center code block, the application should first retrieve the updated list and then access that list to plot pins on the map. Every time an update is received, the application will clear all pins from the map and then replot the pins based on the updated list (inefficient we know, but this is a temporary solution). However, the pins are never updated. Through the use of the debugger we have discovered that once map.Pins.Clear() within PlotPins() is called, the application jumps to the end of the RequestUpdatedListAsync method (which occurs periodically to retrieve the updated list and which triggers the Messaging Center) and then halts.

Our solution works for our GTK build, with the pins being cleared and redrawn on the map as intended, so this seems to be an Android specific issue.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Relevant code located below:

MESSAGING CENTER:

```cs
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, ObservableCollection<MyObject>>(Application.Current, Constants.ListUpdateContract, (sender, newList) =>
            { 
                //update list
                listUpdater.UpdateList(newList);
                //call method to plot pins again
                PlotPins(map);
            });
```

PLOTPINS:

```cs
private void PlotPins(Map map)
        {
            map.Pins.Clear();
            foreach (MyObject in MyObjects)
            {
                var pin = new Pin
                {
                    Label = MyObject.ID,
                    Address = "Latitude: " + MyObject.Latitude + " " + "Longitude: " + MyObject.Longitude,
                    Type = PinType.Place,
                    Position = new Position(Convert.ToDouble(MyObject.Latitude), Convert.ToDouble(MyObject.Longitude))
                };
                //event handler for when user clicks on pin's info window
                pin.InfoWindowClicked += async (s, args) =>
                {
                    //opens up detail page for pin associated with myObject
                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailPage(MyObject));
                };

                map.Pins.Add(pin);
            }

        }
```

REQUEST UPDATED LIST ASYNC:

```cs
public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool> RequestUpdatedListAsync()
        {
            if (!_tokenIsGood)
                return false;
            var success = false;
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage();


            try
            {
                response = await _client.GetAsync(Constants. MyObjectDisplayUrl);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error requesting updated list.");
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                return success;
            }

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            success = true;
            var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            // Update list
            MyObjects.Clear();
            MyObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection< MyObject >>(responseBody);

            //Alert subscribed ViewModels to update list
            MessagingCenter.Send<object, ObservableCollection< MyObject >>(Application.Current, Constants.ListUpdateContract, units);


            return success;
        }
```

Comment: Try updating the map on main thread. MessagingCenter invocations are not run on main thread by default.

Comment: Which line does it halt?, as @shanranm suggested try `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` since `maps.Pins.clear()` should run on main UI thread.

Comment: @shanranm Thank you guys! I made the map clearing line into it's own method and ran both the new ClearMap and PlotPins methods to run on the main thread! It is now working how I intended it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `maps.Pins` is UI related it has to be run in main UI thread.

`MessagingCenter` doesnt always publish/subscribe in main threads .

So to fix this issue call the `maps.Pins.Clear()` in main thread.

```cs
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(()=> maps.Pins.Clear());
```

Credits: [@shanranm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5032316/shanranm) for mentioning limitation of `MessagingCenter` for using main threads.